# make modal popup while clicking on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple html design with an animated menu. I am trying to implement bootstrap on it and make modal window. But when someone clicks at contact, my animated menu stops working. [Here](https://realcredit.ge/) you can check the problem.

My modal code here. I'm using #mymodal on menu link.

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Jquery

```
$(document).on("click",".menu",function(){

      $("#myModal").modal("show")
})
```